# Is it possible to load the css just on my plugin admin page?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin-css

I am trying to build a wp plugin using vuejs and the bulma css framework, but it seems like it is having an impact on the whole admin area.

Is it possible to load my css only on my plugin admin page?

Comment: Did you read the documentation ?   https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Load_CSS_File_from_a_plugin_on_specific_Admin_Page

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, [from the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Load_CSS_File_from_a_plugin_on_specific_Admin_Page), listed above in the comments.

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        // Load only on ?page=mypluginname
        if($hook != 'toplevel_page_mypluginname') {
                return;
        }
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Note: If you are unsure what your $hook name is .. use this to determine your hookname. Put the code after the { from the function.

```
wp_die($hook);
```